# Extracting data/string from Pandas DF column

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract currency pairs from the poloniex API using Python pandas.

I believe the data returned is all just a single column name:

```
Columns: [{"BTC_BCN":{"BTC":"479.74697466", "BCN":"1087153595.32266165"}, "BTC_BELA":{"BTC":"32.92293515", "BELA":"1807337.13247948"}, "BTC_BLK":{"BTC":"25.70374054", "BLK":"606717.86348734"}, "BTC_BTCD":{"BTC":"24.32220571", "BTCD":"1264.02352237"}, "BTC_BTM":{"BTC":"11.57816905", "BTM":"80673.47934437"}, "BTC_BTS":{"BTC":"1102.88787610", "BTS":"30426626.64558044"}
```

The result I want: `BTC_BCN, BTC_BELA, BTC_BLK,` etc...

But not really sure if there is a simple way to get this without string parsing since they all appear to just be column names.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
try:
  from StringIO import StringIO
except:
   from io import StringIO



sock= urllib2.urlopen('https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume')
link=sock.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')
csv_data = StringIO(soup.text)

df=pd.read_csv(csv_data,delimiter=' *, *',engine='python')
df2=df.iloc[1:2,0:20]
```

Comment: to get columns names you can do `list(df.columns)`

Comment: list(df.keys()) seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `BeautifulSoup` here at all. *The contents of the webpage is JSON* - parse it with [`.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) directly:

```
df = pd.read_json('https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume')
```